# C# deserialize pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a large list of objects that needs to be displayed in HTML table. I retrieve the list using BinaryFormatter like so:

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
MyObject obj = (MyObject) formatter.Deserialize(fromStream);
stream.Close();
```

Can Deserialize() method return first 100 records and then next 100 and so on?

Answer (score 1):

> Can Deserialize() method return first 100 records and then next 100
>   and so on?

The short answer is no.

1) However you can either step through the deserialized objects such as addresses in the below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public class App 
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Serialize();
        Deserialize();
    }

    static void Serialize() 
    {
        // Create a hashtable of values that will eventually be serialized.
        Hashtable addresses = new Hashtable();
        addresses.Add("Jeff", "123 Main Street, Redmond, WA 98052");
        addresses.Add("Fred", "987 Pine Road, Phila., PA 19116");
        addresses.Add("Mary", "PO Box 112233, Palo Alto, CA 94301");

        // To serialize the hashtable and its key/value pairs,  
        // you must first open a stream for writing. 
        // In this case, use a file stream.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

        // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        try 
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, addresses);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally 
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }


    static void Deserialize() 
    {
        // Declare the hashtable reference.
        Hashtable addresses  = null;

        // Open the file containing the data that you want to deserialize.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
        try 
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            // Deserialize the hashtable from the file and 
            // assign the reference to the local variable.
            addresses = (Hashtable) formatter.Deserialize(fs);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally 
        {
            fs.Close();
        }

        // To prove that the table deserialized correctly, 
        // display the key/value pairs.
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in addresses) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} lives at {1}.", de.Key, de.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

2) Choose a different approach to encoding your binary data in the first place, so that you can sequentially read it as needed. So for instance you could writer a custom serializer that first put out the number of bytes to read as a sequence of bytes based on the size of the object you are streaming some basic code would be:

`int read = stream.Read(data, offset, remaining);`

In fact writing your own serializer so that you *know* how the data is serialized and so that you can deserialize it piecemeal as you need is probably worth the effort if that is your requirement.

3) Rely on a 3rd party package that effeciently serializes your data and allows you to sequentually read things. There are heaps out there just do some Googling will find heaps but you can look say at Google Protocol Buffers which is size efficient and fast. See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial which has a few examples of some of the things I have discussed.